# Pyinstaller: Import Error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, pyqt, python-3.5, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm trying create an executable from my code that uses PyQt5. I'm using Python 3.5.3 -64 bits, developing in Windows 10, and used pip to install pyinstaller 3.2.1.

I run pyinstaller as such:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed main.py
```

I get an Import Error:

```
File "C:\Python35\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module> load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2291, in load
return self.resolve()
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
import PyInstaller.building.build_main
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 32, in <module>
from ..depend import bindepend
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 38, in <module>
from ..utils.win32.winmanifest import RT_MANIFEST
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 97, in <module>
from PyInstaller.utils.win32 import winresource
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 20, in <module>
import pywintypes
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
__import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 64, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
import _win32sysloader
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've read that this meanings pywin32 was not installed by pip and that I need to install this Microsoft Visual Package: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555. I downloaded and installed it but I'm getting the same error.

**Edit:**

After installing pywin32 from sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20221, the import error is gone but I'm getting warnings when it's running (the output is hundreds of lines long, here is a snippet):

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

....

```
3220 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python35\python.exe

3251 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python35\python.exe

3267 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python35\python.exe

3305 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python35\python.exe

3336 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python35\python.exe
```

....

```
9265 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Core.dll dependency of C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll

9297 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll

9333 WARNING: lib not found: Qt5Gui.dll dependency of C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll

9366 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll
```

Then I run:

```
pyinstaller main.spec
```

and get similar warnings. The resulting exe file closes immediately.

Comment: try run it without windowed or use the spec file instead

Comment: Running it without windowed didn't work. What is the spec file?

Comment: run ```pyinstaller file.py``` then a file called ```file.spec``` is created

Comment: use the spec file instead of the python file ```pyinstaller file.spec```

Comment: It created a folder, but displayed a lot of warnings. When I run the application it created it immediately closes.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: I've added some of it to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install pyinstaller and pywin32, which is same bit version as your python bit version is.

Get it from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20214/

choose amd64 ones if your python is 64-bit else non-amd64 ones

If you face any registry problems (or) Python installation directory not found issues, I can help

Comment: I'm not seeing a version for Python 3.5.  I downloaded and ran pywin32-214.win-amd64-py3.1.exe but it wants Python 3.1.

Comment: I installed pywin32-221.win-amd64-py3.5 and that seems to have solved the import problem. I'm now getting lots of "WARNING: lib not found: ..." as it's running.