# pyinstaller with pyqt crash

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm currently working on a large project which is based on a pyqt5 GUI. Usually I convert all my releases of this project with pyinstaller to a .exe file. Somehow from one day to another this didn't work anymore.

Now when I create an executable it shows the console for 1sec and then immediately closes without an error. So I started investigating and found out, that pyqt5 must be causing issues. I tried compiling the following really simple GUI to an executable and the same thing happens as with my main project:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("Hello World")
        l = QtWidgets.QLabel("My simple app.")
        l.setMargin(10)
        self.setCentralWidget(l)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    app.exec()
```

Compiling the exact same code on a colleges machine just works fine, so we exported his conda env to a .yml file and cloned it to my machine, but I'm still not able to get a working executable even with his env. I can run his compiled exe just fine. Now I ran out of ideas. I hope someone could help me with this issue. Compiling something like:

```
x = input("enter a number")
print(x)
```

works fine as executable. I also tried compiling older versions of my project which worked fine as .exe before with no success.

windows10  python == 3.6.4   PyQt5 == 5.15.1   pyinstaller == 4.0

EDIT:
Now I found out, that when I compile it as single file not as directory, the exe is a little bit slower and there was a error msg popping up for a few milliseconds. So I ran the exe in cmd and got the following error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_env.py", line 1, in <module>
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specific module could not be found.
[6996] Failed to execute script test_env
```

Comment: make sure you compile it with the same python version as pyinstaller installed. i did encounter this whenever I used pyinstaller from another python version. also check your pip list

Comment: [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658534/pyinstaller-import-error-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-fo) might help your problem

Comment: After many attempts i finally found a solution. The problem was that for whatever reason pyinstaller wasnt able to pack all necessary .dlls from pyqt. Adding: "/Miniconda3/envs/env/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/bin" to the pyinstaller "--path" solved my problem.